# how to correct wrong or shortened written words

Tags: algorithm, spell-checking

I have to fix a problem related to a large number of user generated skills.
Users can put any skills on their profiles and i want to merge the ones that are the same:
I have this pairs (among others):
React, React Js, React.js, reactjs
MS Office, Microsoft Office
MS Word, Microsoft Word

I tried the Levenshtein algorithm and different spell checkers but they do not work in such cases.

Does anyone know a solution for a problem like this?

Comment: How exactly didn't the Levenshtein distance work? Was the edit distance larger than expected?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this problem, there are 2 solutions:

- build an exhaustive list of all possible skills you consider equal
- define a suitable 'distance' between two given skills and define a threshold you feel yields good (enough) results

**Suppose you are going with the first option, then the pseudocode is pretty simple:**

1. for any list of skills the user enters, loop over each skill S
2. if S is in the set of 'accepted' skills, then keep S
3. if S does not belong to the set of 'accepted' skills, check whether an accepted skill S2 has S as one of its variants. If it does, return S2

**Suppose you are going with the second option:**

1. for any list of skills the user enters, loop over each skill S
2. set S to uppercase
3. split S by any token that is not [A-Z], name this Sp
4. sort Sp alphabetically
5. re-join the tokens in Sp by space, name this Sc
6. use the Levenshtein distance to compare Sc to other items in the list of skills

e.g.

> React, React Js, React.js, reactjs

React --> REACT --> [REACT] --> [REACT] --> REACT
React Js --> REACT JS --> [REACT JS] --> [JS REACT] --> JS REACT // distance 3
React.js --> REACT.JS --> [REACT JS] --> [JS REACT] --> JS REACT // distance 0